# iOS 7 Auto Layout vs. iOS 8 Adaptive Layout, is there a difference?

Tags: ios8, autolayout, adaptive-layout

Is there a difference between iOS 7 Auto Layout and iOS 8 Adaptive Layout?
Or is it just -the adaptive layout- a more enhanced version with more features to help building more flexible layouts that fit different screen sizes?

I really can't figure out a real difference between both terms, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Working with autolayout in iOS 7 and iOS 8 is the same. Adaptive layout is really just an umbrella term for all the new layout tools in Xcode 6 and iOS 8-- one of which being Autolayout. Though autolayout isn't new, it's still a part of the adaptive layout toolset, and it's much improved in iOS 8. Other adaptive layout tools include **Size Classes** and **Adaptive Fonts**. I recommend reading this Ray Wenderlich article that has some examples of the new tools: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Answer (score 5):

Auto Layout: With Auto Layout, you can define constraints to control how your user interface adapts immediately to any size changes

Adaptive Layout: Design once in common storyboard and use for both iPad and iPhone.